# Check if string contains any non digit character - no libraries - Java

Tags: java, regex

This might be clear to someone familiar with regex expressions but I am not.

Example:

```
String onlyNumbers = "1233444";
String numbersAndDigits = "123344FF";

if (IS_ONLY_NUMBERS(onlyNumbers))
    return true;

if (IS_ONLY_NUMBERS(numbersAndDigits))
    return false;
```

Suggestions? Is there a way to do a similar check without importing libraries?

Comment: `yourString.matches("\\d+")` will do the trick. If this is false, you have non digits in your string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `String.matches("\\d+")`. If that statement returns false, then there are characters in your string that are not digits. `\d` means the character must be a digit, and the `+` means that every character must be a digit.

Like so:

```
String onlynumbers = "1233444";
String numbersanddigits = "123344FF";

System.out.println(onlynumbers.matches("\\d+")); // prints "true"
System.out.println(numbersanddigits.matches("\\d+")); // prints "false"
```

Comment: @JackScotti Stackoverflow is no competi... oh... wait :-)

Comment: I though `+` means match preceding token 1 or more times.

Comment: That's correct, but I was explaining it to him in terms that he needs to know within the context.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with:

```
if (onlynumbers.matches("[0-9]+")
    return true;

if (numbersanddigits.matches("[0-9]+")
    return false;
```

Also, as a shortcut, you can use `\\d+` instead of `[0-9]+`. It's just a matter of choice which one to pick.

Comment: Just as comment, you could also use the shortcut `\d`